# 404 after processing request for ajax call in console

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I 'm giving an ajax call GET Request to a controller and and the method is getting processed but after completion of execution.it is showing 404 error code in the console of web page.

please find the below code for ajax call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "${home}getOPList",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      //    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
      var operatorList;
      //         alert("yes");
      //         alert(str);

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        console.log(response[i].listOfOperators);
        operatorList += "<option value =' " +
          response[i].sno +
          " '>" +
          response[i].listOfOperators +
          "</option>"

      }
      $('#opList').html(operatorList);

    },

    error: function() {
      alert('Error while request..');
    }
  });
  $("#opList").change(function() {
    var abc = document.getElementById('opList').value;
    alert("we got :: " + abc);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "${home}partnerDetails?operator=" + abc,
      data: {
        operator: abc
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        //    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
        var partnerList;
        alert("yes");
        alert("oplist " + abc);

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          console.log(response[i].campaignName);
          partnerList += "<option value =' " +
            response[i].sno +
            " '>" +
            response[i].campaignName +
            "</option>"

        }
        $('#ptList').html(partnerList);

      },

      error: function() {
        alert('Error while request in partners..');
      }
    });

  });
});
```

and please find the controller code

```
@Controller
public class PartnerController {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PartnerController.class.getName());
@Autowired
public UserService userService;

@Autowired
   public Gson gson;




public Gson getGson() {
    return gson;
}




public void setGson(Gson gson) {
    this.gson = gson;
}




public UserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}




public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}




 @RequestMapping(value ="/partnerDetails" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String  getPartnerList(String operator){
    logger.info(" \t OP IN REQUEST :: "+operator);
    String partnerList = "";

    try{
     ArrayList<PartnersList> arrayList =     

(ArrayList<PartnersList>)userService.getPartnersListFromDB();
 logger.info(" \t PARTNERS LIST BEFORE CONVERSION :: "+arrayList);
     partnerList = gson.toJson(arrayList);
     logger.info(" \t PARTNERS LIST :: "+partnerList);

    }catch(Exception e){


        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return partnerList;
}
```

}

i'm able to print the last logger and return statement and the code is getting excuted but some how i'm not able to get the alert popup on web page and the last alert was that "we got " one and then the code is getting processed in controller method and getting 404 in the console like below please help me on this.

```
 GET XHR http://localhost/Promotions/partnerDetails [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 40ms]
```

Comment: I'm guessing `"${home}getOPList"` should be `\`${home}getOPList\``

Comment: Put `localhost/Promotions/partnerDetails?operator=some_valid_value_for_operator` into the address bar of your browser and then go solve the fact your server is not returning anything before you worry about the javascript.

Comment: @skylize,when getOPList is working fine then i hope partnerDetails should work in the same way

Comment: @skylize , I tried the above path but nothing was changed still it says the same getting 404 error ,pls help me on this

Comment: @RameshRaj I'm sorry, all I can tell you is that your server is not sending a valid response. Your ajax call is not the problem, no way to check the ajax call for possible bugs until your server is sending data. That's why I suggested the address bar, because you can just hit refresh and see yes/no without worrying if your ajax is gonna work. I don't see anything in the code you shared that gives me any clue how your server is trying to produce an html response to your query.

Comment: got the solution added @ResponseBody to the method.all worked fine